# Несоответствие возвращаемых типов

Tags: java, ооп

Хочу добавить наследнику `ByteArrayOutputStream` поддержку интерфейса `SeekableByteChannel`. Проблема в методе `size()`. Для `ByteArrayOutputStream` он объявлен как

```
public int size()
```

А для `SeekableByteChannel`

```
long size()
```

Если оставить базовую реализацию или продублировать свою

```
public int size() {
    return super.size();
}
```

То получаю две ошибки

> Error:(12, 8) java: ByteArrayOutputSeekableStream is not abstract and does not override abstract method size() in java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel
>
> Error:(147, 17) java: size() in ByteArrayOutputSeekableStream cannot override size() in java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
>     return type long is not compatible with int

Если метод переопределить

```
public long size() {
    return super.size();
}
```

то получаю ошибки

> Error:(157, 17) java: size() in ByteArrayOutputSeekableStream cannot override size() in java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
>     return type long is not compatible with int
>
> Error:(37, 16) java: size() in BufferedOutputSeekableStream cannot implement size() in java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel
>     return type int is not compatible with long
>
> Error:(38, 26) java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int

Проблема как-то решается? Или нужно добавлять в класс метод

```
public SeekableByteChannel getChannel();
```

и отдавать какой-то адаптер?

Comment: Напрямую реализовать такое не получится так, как java не поддерживает наследование двух методов с одинаковыми аргументами.

Comment: А приведение типов не поможет?

Comment: @sapeg Приведение типов где? Проблема не в теле метода, а в невозможности объявить сам метод

Comment: jvm позволяет использовать методы с разными возвращаемыми типами, но язык java - нет. Была [статья](https://web.archive.org/web/20081019232211/http://today.java.net:80/pub/a/today/2008/07/31/return-type-based-method-overloading.html#is-this-useful) в которой такой класс писали с помощью ассемблера

Answer (score 1):

Ну собственно ты сам и ответил на свой вопрос. Переопределить метод нельзя, базовую реализацию тоже оставить не получится, не нарушив принципов ООП (что собственно компилятор тебе сделать и не дает). Так-же это можно было увидеть, прочитав [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2). 
Адаптер? А почему нет? В данном случае - достаточно хорошее решение.